# How to change the checked property of ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, listview, lambda

I've a ListView with two columns and i'm filling the ListView using the  code below

```
        ListViewItem[] l_lvItem = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(X => new ListViewItem(new String[] {X.ToString(),(X+1).ToString() })).ToArray();
        listView1.Items.AddRange(l_lvItem);
```

Here is the output of the above code

[image]

But the need like

[image]

I've enabled the `Checkboxes` property of my listView. But i cannot change the checked property of the each item using the above code.

Using `for/foreach` loop i can change the property,

but just need to a simple way .

Please help me to modify/rewrite my above code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
ListViewItem[] l_lvItem = (from X in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                   select new ListViewItem(new String[] { X.ToString(), (X + 1).ToString() }) { Checked = true }).ToArray();
listView1.Items.AddRange(l_lvItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change all them to checked with one function call or w/e.

You need to loop through each element and change it after you have added them all.